# Proof Check: The Product rule via Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I've been working on the following proof of the product rule for derivatives using Taylor series. Are there any holes? Thanks.

Setup:

Let $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ be some interval. Let $f,g:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$ both be continuous and differentiable on $I$. Suppose that $\forall n\in A=\{0,1,2,...\}$, $f^{(n)}(x)$ and $g^{(n)}(x)$ (the $n$-th derivatives of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively) are continuous on $I$.

Edit:

Suppose that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ on $I$, and that the Taylor series of $g(x)$ converges to $g(x)$ on $I$.

Theorem: If $u(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then $u'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$.

Proof:

Let $m\in I$ be some constant.
$$\therefore f(x)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{f^{(n)}(m)}{n!}(x-m)^{n}, g(x)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{g^{(n)}(m)}{n!}(x-m)^{n}$$
Let $f_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(m)}{n!}$, $g_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(m)}{n!}$, which are constants for all $n\in A$.
$$\therefore f(x)=\sum_{n\in A}f_n\cdot(x-m)^n,  g(x)=\sum_{n\in A}g_n\cdot(x-m)^n$$
$$\therefore f'(x)=\sum_{n\in A}nf_n\cdot(x-m)^{n-1}, g'(x)=\sum_{n\in A}ng_n\cdot(x-m)^{n-1}$$
Let $u(x)=f(x)g(x)$
$$\therefore u(x)=(\sum_{n_1\in A}f_{n_1}\cdot(x-m)^{n_1})(\sum_{n_2\in A}g_{n_2}\cdot(x-m)^{n_2})$$
$$\therefore u(x)=\sum_{n_1\in A}\sum_{n_2\in A}f_{n_1}g_{n_2}(x-m)^{n_1+n_2}$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=\sum_{n_1\in A}\sum_{n_2\in A}f_{n_1}g_{n_2}(n_1+n_2)(x-m)^{n_1+n_2-1}$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=\sum_{n_1\in A}\Biggl((\sum_{n_2\in A}f_{n_1}g_{n_2}n_1(x-m)^{n_1+n_2-1})+(\sum_{n_3\in A}f_{n_1}g_{n_3}n_3(x-m)^{n_1+n_3-1})\Biggl)$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=\sum_{n_1\in A}\Biggl([n_1f_{n_1}(x-m)^{n_1-1}\sum_{n_2\in A}g_{n_2}(x-m)^{n_2}]+[f_{n_1}(x-m)^{n_1}\sum_{n_3\in A}n_3g_{n_3}(x-m)^{n_3-1}]\Biggl)$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=\sum_{n_1\in A}\Biggl(n_1f_{n_1}(x-m)^{n_1-1}g(x)+f_{n_1}(x-m)^{n_1}g'(x)\Biggl)$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=\Biggl(g(x)\sum_{k_1\in A}k_1f_{k_1}(x-m)^{k_1-1}\Biggl)+\Biggl(g'(x)\sum_{k_2\in A}f_{k_2}(x-m)^{k_2}\Biggl)$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=g(x)f'(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$
$$\therefore u'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
QED

Comment: It is possible that $f$ be differentiable yet its Taylor series converge but not to $f$.

Comment: @Randall honestly I have no idea. I hadn't considered that. Do such functions exist?

Comment: Yes, something like $e^{-1/x^2}$ made continuous at 0.

Comment: @Randall Thanks. I'll update the proof then.

Comment: @Randall how about now? I just added more to the setup.